# Variables in 6 components PLSR using pls package in R?

Tags: r, statistics, pls

My mentor asked me to use PLSR in R to analyze some data he had sitting around. I used the pls package and created a mvr workspace object using the following syntax:

```
posamodel <- plsr(posa ~ ados_css + sex_info + age_mdevhist_match + kbit_iqstand_score + 
                    evt_ss_std + scq_total_score + tomi_total + qpq_conflict_sum + 
                    spp_c_a_t_social + spp_c_a_p_social + spp_c_a_s_social + cabs_total + 
                    DANVA_faces_total + DANVA_voices_total + Cz.Voices_N100.L + 
                    Cz.Voices_N100.V + P7.Faces_N170_AVG.L + P8.Faces_N170_AVG.L + 
                    LPC_Correct_avg + LPC_Incorrect_avg + LPC_diff_correct_incorrect + 
                    nega + lowa, data=data, validation="CV")
```

I examined validation plots using the following:

```
validationplot(posamodel)
```

[image: [Validation plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF2IF.png)]

Judging by this, I determined the correct number of components to be 6.

Here's where my trouble is. I want to know, for N=6 components, which variables map onto which component. I can't seem to find an easy way to do this with pls, although it seems like a basic functionality. Is there something I'm missing?

I tried loadings(posamodel) and tried specifying NCOMP = 6 (I tried both in the initial PLSR command and in the loadings command) This looks like it's getting closer to what I want, but my attempts at specifying 6 components didn't work.